# How can I read the contents of stdin (up until EOF) into a string in PHP?

Tags: php, stream

How can I read the contents of stdin (up until EOF) into a string in PHP?

Answer (score 74):

ended up figuring it out myself:

```
$input_data = file_get_contents("php://stdin");
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's an alternative: You can use `stream_get_contents` to get everything from an open stream (AKA a file handle). `STDIN` is an already open handle equivalent to what you get if you call `fopen('php://stdin')` (see reference: [Input/output streams](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php))

So: you can use

```
$input_data = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

which is equivalent to [the accepted answer](/a/823533/19966).

Answer (score 6):

Use some of the file reading functions (e.g. `fgets()`, `fgetc()`, `fscanf()`) and pass in `STDIN` as the file path (or `php://stdin`, depending on how new your version of PHP is).

You can test for the EOF using [`feof()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php).

See the [reference for command-line programming in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) on PHP.net for more information.